# Solve the mystery of the poisonous chemical

Tags: riddle

*Dr. Joblet* just produced a new chemical called C-15. It was found to be the most poisonous chemical such that even touching it could kill anybody. He produced the chemical in his own laboratory which was strictly guarded. He hired some partners to help him in his work including some more security guards because he knew he was working on a serious project. No one was allowed to enter the lab without the doctor's permission. If anyone tries to enter the lab, the guards will not let him pass. If he makes it inside then the alarms will start buzzing and the laser wall may pierce his body.

Unfortunately, two of the hired people decide to rob the chemical for illegal use. Next day, the doctor went to a meeting. *Labo*, one of those two decided to stay outside and wait for him, while *Gyro* decided to go inside to get the chemical. *Gyro*  went safely inside without having the alarms buzz or lasers on. He took the chemical from a locker. *Labo* waited for *Gyro* but after a min, he thought they were gonna get caught. He ran away for his life. The other day, one of them was found to be dead.

The questions are:

> Who died and how?
>   How did *Gyro* went inside the lab safely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did Gyro went inside the lab safely?

1. > Credit to @Quantoss: Labo and Gyro were security guards.
2. > Gyro got inside with no problem beacause as a guard he knew how to disable security.

Who died and how?

1. > However, as a guard and not a scientist, he did not know what precautions to take when handling the chemical, so he just touched it and died.
2. > Labo saw it and knew that they are gonna get caught, because Gyro was dead inside the facility with the chemical spilled on the floor.

Alternative ending:

1. > Labo thought they were gonna get caught because after a minute he saw that they were being recorded by a security camera.
2. > Any one of them (or even both) could be found dead because of what they did.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that

> Either *Gyro* or *Labo* (or both) was security guard, thus they were able to open the lab, disable security measures and enter safely.

And who died?

> My guess that *Gyro* was found dead inside the lab. Here's my reasoning:
>  To open the lab door you need a guard do something (swipe his card, enter his code, etc.) and it's only possible from the outside. *Labo* opened the door, *Gyro* entered, and door was closed. After a minute *Labo* ran away and there was noone to open the door again (since it's possible only from the outside). So *Gyro* was stuck inside the lab and either died of hunger/thirst or security measures turned themselves on after some time and killed *Gyro*.

Comment: How can Gyro die of hunger? Doctor will be back after a few hours

Comment: That's why i wrote the second option , rot13(gur ynfref ner orvat qvfnoyrq bayl sbe n frg crevbq bs gvzr, fb gurl ghearq ba ntnva naq cvreprq Tleb). But i guess that's not it?

Comment: You are creative... I see